# Parallel and distributed algorithms for matrix multiplication

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, big-o, matrix-multiplication

The problem comes when I looked up Wikipedia page of [**Matrix multiplication algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm#Shared-memory_parallelism)

It says:

> This algorithm has a critical path length of **`Θ((log n)^2)`** steps, meaning it takes that much time on an ideal machine with an infinite number of processors; therefore, it has a **maximum possible speedup** of `Θ(n3/((log n)^2))` on any real computer.

(*The quote is from section "Parallel and distributed algorithms/Shared-memory parallelism."*)

Since assuming there are infinite processors, the operation of multiplication should be done in `O(1)`. And then just add all elements up, and this should be a constant time as well. Therefore, the longest critical path should be *O(1) instead of Θ((log n)^2)*.

I was wondering if there is difference between O and Θ and where am I mistaken?

---

The problem has been solved, big thanks to @Chris Beck. The answer should be separated into two parts.

First, a low mistake is I do not count the time of summation. The summation takes `O(log(N))` in operation<sub>( think about binary adding )</sub>.

Second, as Chris points out, the non-trivial problems takes time `O(log(N))` in the processor. Above all, the longest critical path should be `O(log(N)^2)` instead of `O(1)`.

For confusion of O and Θ, I found the answer in [Big_O_Notation_Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

> Big O is the most commonly used asymptotic notation for comparing functions, although in many cases Big O may be replaced with Big Theta Θ for asymptotically tighter bounds.

---

I was wrong for the last conclusion. The `O(log(N)^2)` does not happen at summation and processor, but happen at when we split the matrix. Thanks @displayName for reminding me of this. In addition, Chris' answer for non trivial problem is still very useful for researching parallel system. Thank all warm heart answerers below!

Comment: What you describe is not what the algorithm does. It uses division and recursion

Comment: Very good question. I hope this one is noticed by some good minds at SO. I'll try to answer this question. Till then, please go through what "Critical Path Length" means.

Comment: @displayName, many thanks. Actually, I have looked up the explanation in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_parallel_algorithms). I think it is similar to the worst case in algorithm. The term is defined for parallel computation. So, we consider the slowest processor operating time as the result. However, it does not help me to solve the problem above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are two aspects to this question, addressing which the question will be completely answered.**

- *Why can't we bring the run-time to O(1) by throwing in sufficient number of processors?*
- *How is the critical path length for Matrix Multiplication equal to Θ(log<sup>2</sup>n)?*

Going after the questions one by one.

---

### Infinite number of processors

The simple answer to this point is in understanding two terms viz. *Task Granularity* and *Task Dependency*.

- ***Task Granularity -*** implies how fine the task decomposition is. Even if you have infinite processors, the maximum decomposition is still finite for a problem.
- ***Task Dependency -*** implies that what are the steps that simply can be performed sequentially only. Like, you cannot modify the input unless you have read it. So modifying will always be preceded by reading of the input and cannot be done in parallel with it.

So, for a process that has four steps `A, B, C, D` such that *D is dependent on C, C is dependent on B and B is dependent on A*, then a single processor will work as fast as 2 processors, will work as fast as 4 processors, will work as fast as infinite processors.

This explains the first bullet.

---

### Critical Path Length for Parallel Matrix Multiplication

1. If you had to divide a square matrix of size `n X n` into four blocks of size `[n/2] X [n/2]` each and then continue dividing until you reach down to a single element (or matrix of size `1 X 1`) the number of levels this *tree-like* design would have is *O(log (n))*.
2. Thus, for matrix multiplication in parallel, since we have to recursively divide not one but two matrices of size n, down to their last element, it takes *O(log<sup>2</sup>n)* time.
3. In fact, this bound is tighter and is not just *O(log<sup>2</sup>n)*, but *Θ(log<sup>2</sup>n)*.

The difference between Big O and Theta is that Big O only tells that a process won't go above what's mentioned by Big O, while Theta tells that function is not just having an upper bound, but also the lower bound with what's mentioned in Theta. Hence, effectively, the *plot* of the complexity of the function would be sandwiched between the same function, multiplied with two different constants as depicted in the image below, or in other words, the function will grow at the same rate:

[image]

<sup>*Image taken from: http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/Images/thetaGraph.gif*</sup>

So, I'd say that for your case, you can ignore the notation and you are not "gravely" mistaken between the two.

---

### To conclude...

I'd like to define another term called **Speedup or Parallelism**. It is defined as the *ratio of best sequential execution time (also called work) and parallel execution time.* The best sequential access time, already given on the wikipedia page you've linked to is *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*. The parallel execution time is *O(log<sup>2</sup>n)*.

**Hence, the speedup is = *O(n<sup>3</sup>/log<sup>2</sup>n)*.**

And even though the speedup looks so simple and straightforward, achieving it in actual cases is very difficult due to *the communication costs that are inherent in moving data.*

Comment: So, processors can ideally operate the single element pair multiplication in O(1). The O(log(N)^2) happens when we split the matrix to single element. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @JerroldGao: Yes, that is the idea. Breaking down the computation to finest level possible recursively. That gives that run-time.

Comment: @JerroldGao: I have done one small addition in the solution. Please go through the answer again if you are interested...

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is very useful for algorithm analysis, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

"Infinite number of processors" is perhaps a poor way of phrasing it.

When people study parallel computation from a theoretical viewpoint, they basically want to ask "assuming I have more processors than I need, how fast can I possibly do it".

It's a well-defined question -- just because you have a huge number of processors doesn't mean matrix multiplication is O(1).

Suppose you take any naive algorithm for matrix multiplication on a single processor. Then I tell you, you can have one processor for every single assembly instruction if you like, so the program can be "parallelized" in that each processor performs only a single instruction and then shares its result with the next.

The time of that computation is not "1" cycle, because some of the processors have to wait for other processors to finish, and those processors are waiting on different processors, etc.

Generally speaking, nontrivial problems (problems in which none of the input bits are irrelevant) require time `O(log n)` in parallel computation, otherwise the "answer" processor at the very end doesn't even have time to depend on all of the input bits.

Problems for which `O(log n)` parallel time is tight, are said to be highly parallelizable. It is widely conjectured that some of them don't have this property. If that's not true, then in terms of computational complexity theory, `P` would collapse to a lower class which it is conjectured not to.

Comment: Very accessible explanation. Doesn't address the Big-O vs. Theta distinction, but otherwise nice.

Comment: The answer seems to be plausible. Thanks! But wait for moment, I may have some questions to ask tonight since I have to look it carefully.

Comment: Yes, the answer solved the problem. However, I do not fully understand why we take nontrivial problems or number as O(log(n))?

Comment: Most accessible explanation (in keeping with answer I gave) is like this. On any machine for any processor, there is some finite instruction set, and each primitive instruction touches some constant (O(1)) number of registers. Let C be the largest of these constants. At the zeroth time step, the only data available is the input, and each register then depends on O(1) bits of input. If at t'th time step, no register depends on more than K bits of the input, then at t+1'th time step, no register depends on more than C * K. If output must depend on all `n` bits, we need `t` at least `log_C (n)`

Comment: I think twice about you answer. If we consider about bits in the input, we discuss a different n for the question. Once we put matrix elements in to processor state, we no longer think about the contribution due to matrix size since every processors operates one element. Therefore, I think displayName has more plausible answer. But thank you for introducing non trivial problem consideration to me.

Comment: @JerroldGao: I think it's really the same argument, but you can think of it however you like of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication can be done in `O(logn)` using `n^3` processors. Here is how:

Input: two `N x N` matrices `M1` and `M2`. `M3` will store the result.

Assign `N` processors to compute the value of `M3[i][j]`. `M3[i][j]` is defined as `Sum(M1[i][k] * M2[k][j]), k = 1..N`. In the first step all processors do a single multiplication. First one does `M1[i][1] * M2[1][j]`, second one does `M1[i][2] * M2[2][j]`, ... . Each processor keeps its value. Now we have to sum all these multiplied pairs. We can do this in `O(logn)` time if we organize the summation into a tree:

```
     4         Stage 3
   /   \
  2     2      Stage 2
 / \   / \
1   1 1   1    Stage 1
```

We run this algorithm in parallel for all `(i, j)` using `N^3` processors.