# What is speedup and how its calculated?

Tags: database, performance, hive, benchmarking

Im seeing in some studies about paralell systems and I see a lot comparisons in terms of speedup. But Im not understanding well this speedup concept, it seems that is something about verify what happens with the system as we increase the number of nodes. But what is good to happen or what should happen and why? And how we calculate this speed up? For example if we have the execution time of somes queries in hive for 1 and 3 nodes.

1 node:

q1= 24

q2= 59

q3= 58

2 nodes:

q1= 18

q2= 24

q3= 28

Comment: Go to the last section on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32635457/1835769) answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallel and distributed algorithms for matrix multiplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612658/parallel-and-distributed-algorithms-for-matrix-multiplication)

Comment: It looks like your three queries receive different benefits from parallelism.  i.e. the speedup for q1 is much smaller than the speedup from q2.  Other than that, the answer @displayName suggested looks like a good one to link this question to.