# Is parallel linear search O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

Let's imagine we want to search for an element in an array of n elements and we can create as many threads as we want. Let's assign a separate thread for each element of the array and consider that the comparison operation is a lot more expensive than creating threads. Is it valid to say that such searching algorithm is O(1)?

Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class scratch {
    static int[] a = new int[100];
    static final int n = 3;
    static boolean expensiveCompare(int pos) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){}
        return a[pos] == n;
    }

    static AtomicBoolean answer = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public static void main(String... args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        a[2] = 3;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[100];
        for(int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
            final int k = i;
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(expensiveCompare(k)) {
                        answer.compareAndExchange(false, true);
                    }
                }
            });
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            try {
                threads[i].join();
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        System.out.println("Elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        System.out.println("Answer:" + answer);
    }
}
```

Prints: "Elapsed: 1000"

```
public class scratch {
    static final int n = 3;
    static int[] a = new int[100];
    static boolean answer = false;

    static boolean expensiveCompare(int pos) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        return a[pos] == n;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        a[2] = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            answer |= expensiveCompare(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        System.out.println("Answer:" + answer);
    }
}
```

Prints: "Elapsed 100000".

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32612658/1835769) is an interesting question. Not directly related to your question, but a good read overall.

Comment: Speaking of *linear* search is a little risky, because that implies an ordered scanning of the array, an intrinsically sequential process that cannot be parallelized. You should drop the qualifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is O(1), not because of threads, but because the array size is constant (100). If we replace that with a variable, then this:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
```

will already be O(n). It doesn't even matter what you do inside the loop (as long as you don't change `i` or `n`), the loop header alone will already execute an O(n) amount of instructions.

More generally, you can't even start n threads in O(1) time, so starting `n` threads can't give you a running time of O(1) (and of course that's assuming all the threads are even running in parallel, i.e. pretending you have an infinite number of cores).

> consider that the comparison operation is a lot more expensive than creating threads

It does not matter how expensive each operation is. Those are just constants and big-O does not care about constants.

Comment: >You can't even start n threads in less than O(n) time. That's why I note that comparison is more expensive than starting a thread.

Comment: @POrekhov Doing something cheap `n` times is still `O(n)`. Saying that it's cheap just means we're talking about smaller constants, but constants do not matter in big-O.

Comment: But as the number of elements grows, the ratio Search/(Create n threads) grows, and (Create n threads) operation becomes insignificant.

Comment: @POrekhov You could start n threads in O(log n) time, just start two threads that each start two threads etc. I also believe there are also frameworks like cuda where you start n operations in parallel with just one call. So, it all depends on the computational model.

Comment: @POrekhov If starting `n` threads is O(n) and each thread does O(1) amount of work in parallel (again assuming infinite cores/processors), then clearly the `n` is dominating. It doesn't matter that it's cheap, what matters is that it happens linearly often. Let's say that each comparison takes one hour. And let's say starting a thread takes one millisecond. Then for `n > 3600000 ` starting the threads will take longer than performing the comparison. And if we pick different numbers, that will still be true for some other threshold. That's the nature of big-O.

Comment: @sepp2k thanks, I get it. I guess it will only be O(1) if we can start multiple threads in O(1) like Hans Olsson said?

Comment: @POrekhov It will be O(1) if you can start *arbitrarily many* threads in O(1) time. Note that if there were a system that could run an arbitrary number of threads in parallel (by creating new cores on-demand or something like that - a self-replicating CPU of sorts), it would not be physically possible to do that in O(1) time. Outside of theoretical systems, creating an arbitrary amount of something is never possible in O(1) time.

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume that the number of elements N is unbounded and as many thread as wanted can run in parallel.

Let us even assume that all threads are already up and running, to avoid the O(N) cost. Then the comparisons can be done in time O(1), one per thread. But that's not all: you also want to know if the key was found, and optionally by which thread.

This collection of results cannot be performed in O(1) because no processor instruction handles an unbounded number of arguments. As that number is bounded, even ignoring contention on shared memory, the best you can do is to coalesce the N results in a tree-like way (N => N/k => N/k² => N/k³... => 1), and obtain a single result after O(Log N) stages (the number of bits to be processed decreases in a geometric way).

So at best the complexity is O(Log N). [And ironically, if the data is sorted, you can't beat a single thread with a billion ones.]

---

This is a general rule: no problem such that all input data contributes to the solution can be solved in time O(1), whatever the computing power.

This goes deep into physics: you can't build an N-inputs logical gate that is as fast as a 2-inputs one.

Answer (score 2):

Note that even if you have a million of threads, each of them has to be assigned to a particular CPU for execution.

In real life you have a limited number of CPUs or computing nodes. If you have **k** CPUs, it is something like **O(n/k)**, because you do k comparisons at a time.

Now, if k is much less than n (which is typical for PCs), then O(n/k) ~ O(n). Like if your CPU has 4 cores (and it doesn't grow), k = 4, and if n = 100000 potentially, then O(n/k) is still O(n).

If your array is very small, and k is close to n (n/k < C for some constant C), then yes, O(n/k) ~ O(1). Practically speaking if you have a small cluster with 100 cores, and your array is always n < 1000 for example. But in this case it doesn't make much sense to use O-notation, because it is meant to analyze potential cases where n goes to infinity.

Comment: "If you have unlimited computing power, every algorithm becomes O(1)": this is perfectly wrong. A simple operation like taking the XOR of N bits takes at least Log(N) stages, even with an infinity of processors.

Comment: That's true. Changing "every" to "this" to avoid controversialness :)

Comment: I am afraid you didn't fully understand. Even "this" algorithm cannot run in time O(1).

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do you mean? Like some hypothetical large integer `x` where you do something like `x ^ something`? Can you describe to me what you're XORing against?

Comment: @Water: the exact operation is irrelevant (I chose XORing of *single bits* as this is  about the simplest you can think of). You can't XOR N bits in time O(1), and you can even less add N integers nor take the smallest nor...

Comment: @YvesDaoust Something is unclear, you're saying that if you put two words in a register that it's not O(1) to XOR them together? If this is not what you're saying then you're being even more unclear/cryptic and need to clarify (as I'm trying to understand what you are saying).

Comment: @Water: I spoke of N bits, which require N 1-bit registers (or memory slots, as you like).

Comment: @YvesDaoust you are right in the strict math sense. This is because in general if you need to read n items sequentially (and e.g. create tasks/threads of them), you need O(n) time. But I can imagine (for the ideal case) that we read items in parallel too, and don't create tasks/threads. Each CPU sits there and waits to process item i. We snap fingers and they start. Also in practical terms, even if we create threads, but the time is not significant, we can ignore it, so in practical terms it is O(1), although might be O(n) for some huge numbers.

Comment: @battlmonstr: you completely bypassed my explanations. No I am not referring to the O(N) setup time. And no O(1) is not possible. By the way, the question is about asymptotic complexities, a purely mathematical concepts, very far from reality. But I am addressing the question, not the practicalities. (In practice, no computer has an unbounded number of processors.)

Comment: "Also in practical terms, even if we create threads, but the time is not significant, we can ignore it, so in practical terms it is O(1)", Something isn't of O(1) in 'practical terms'. I'm not being pedantic here, it's just plainly wrong to say something like that. Since the number of threads is bound by the size of the input, you cannot ignore this process and the algorithm becomes O(n), regardless of the amount of constant time the starting of the threads costs. It's simply how Big O is defined.

Comment: Assume that the process of task assignment (aka thread creation) is a NOOP, and you do it N times. Is it O(N) or O(1) for you? If it is still O(N) for you, then I'm outta here. It seems to be something where math and programming (or applied math) collide. If the question is about math, and has no practical considerations, it shouldn't be on SO, it should be on cs.stackexchange.com or elsewhere.

Comment: @Glubus: one could accept that the creation of the threads is a form of preprocessing and does not "count" in the total cost if the algorithm is run many times; this is common practice. Or that the machine is of the SIMD type (no thread creation, implicit synchronization) and data is preloaded. Even under these conditions, O(1) is not possible.

Comment: @battlmonstr: asymptotic complexities are asymptotic complexities. If you use the Big-O notation, you must use it with rigor and not decide that "N is small" or "in practice this term is negligible"... This theoretical concept is extremely useful to programmers, provided they know the limitations. Now for the last time, for the search problem, O(1) is not achievable in theory and meaningless in practice.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, about the previous comment, why do you say that if everything is preloaded, it is still O(n)? Is it because you have to anyway combine the results in one way or the other sequentially to find the CPU that got it right, and so this becomes a problem like XOR, i.e. O(n)?

Comment: @battlmonstr: the combination takes at least O(Log N). In practice, you may also need synchronization primitives such as a barrier, which can also be implemented in time O(Log N), but is another reason why O(1) is not possible.

Comment: The deep reason is that you have N arguments and can only combine a finite number of them at a time (often just two).

Comment: Ok, I'll wait 50 years for quantum PCs to come back with my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This question gets at one of the more subtle aspects of big-O notation: the *cost model*.

When we're thinking about how many "steps" a certain algorithm will take to complete a task, we need to decide what we can do in a single step. Most of the time, people will assume a cost model where any basic instruction such as a comparison, a basic arithmetic operation, or a function call costs 1 step. This is a useful simplification even though in real computers those operations can take vastly different amounts of time to execute depending on factors that aren't considered by the model (e.g., are we adding two numbers in registers, in cache, in main memory, on disk?) because doing so lets us think about how the program scales to larger inputs without having to fuss about too many details.

However, in some applications, different cost models are appropriate: for instance, when writing networking software, you might want to count a network transmission as one step and any computation that happens on single node as free, regardless of the algorithm. Similarly, it could be useful to analyze algorithms designed to work well with memory locality based on how many times they need to read from main memory, ignoring the cost of whatever work they do with what they read. None of these approaches is the "right" one -- they're all measuring an abstracted, fictional number -- but they could be useful for different things.

So to answer your question directly: Whether this algorithm is O(1) or O(n) depends on the cost model. If you decide that starting threads is free and that one operation on any number of threads counts as a single step, then yes, it's O(1). If you decide that starting a thread costs a unit of work, or that operation on a single thread counts as a unit of work, then it's O(n). Which cost model is right for your purposes depends on the question you want to answer.

(Being a little less coy, I would say that the first cost model doesn't seem all that useful to me, since I don't know of any situation where I'd want to assume that I can have as many CPUs as I need or that the cost of farming out work is negligible, but maybe if I were analyzing an algorithm for processing data with a big MapReduce cluster or something that would make sense.)

Comment: How can it be O(1) ?

Comment: "Whether this algorithm is O(1) or O(n) depends on the cost model. If you decide that starting threads is free and that one operation on any number of threads counts as a single step, then yes, it's O(1)."

Comment: Can you show me a concept algorithm that can achieve that ? (any kind of description)

Comment: I think I'm not explaining this clearly enough -- it isn't about the algorithm itself, it's about the way we account for its cost. In other words, what are we counting the big-O _of_? For instance, most accounts of big-O never talk about what the cost of running multiple threads is -- are we charging 1 unit of work for each step on any thread, or 1 total unit of work for taking a step on all threads simultaneously? Either choice is defensible depending on what you're trying to figure out about your program.

Comment: The second option is taken, of course. How do you achieve O(1) ?

Comment: Under that assumption plus the assumption that spawning a thread with a chunk of work is free, the given algorithm is O(1) (but only under that cost model, not the implicit one you're thinking of -- usually when we talk about big-O we let the cost model be implicit, but I think that the model was at the heart of OP's confusion).

I think what you're reacting to is the fact that this feels like an unnatural cost model, and I agree that it does. See the last paragraph of my original response.

Comment: It may seem obvious to you that you described an algorithm, but you didn't so far. Try and do it and you'll see.

Comment: I'm talking about the algorithm in the original post. That exact algorithm. Please reread what I've written. I think you think I'm missing the fact that you need to do a linear amount of work to spawn all the threads needed to do the processing. I am not missing that. I am just pointing out that in some analyses, particularly of programs that operate in multiple "locations" (cores / computers / etc) it's useful not to "charge" for that work in our cost model so that we can focus on the more interesting aspects of the distributed computation.

Comment: The program in the OP cannot be used as a reference, you have no information on the complexities of the calls. You keep being stuck on the O(N) issue, which I don't discuss. My claim is that the complexity cannot be lower than O(Log N). I stopping here.